# How to use groups to authenticate KDB users?

Tags: ldap, kdb, torq

I am trying to use LDAP to authenticate users for my KDB app.

The ldap utility I am using https://github.com/KxSystems/ldap/blob/master/docs/reference.md

The only problem is that the institution I am working for prefers using groups instead of authenticating each user. The LDAP utility only shows an example of how to authenticate individual users.

We have used KX Control in the past and the configuration includes those params :

```
groupsFromUser=yes

groupFieldInUser=memberOf
```

Does anyone know how KX ldap func above can be configured for groups ?